# Syntax error in MYSQl trigger creation

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Somewhere around here should be a syntax error, but I really can't find one:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER Mieter_bi BEFORE INSERT ON Mieter FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
 IF NEW.vorname = '' AND NEW.nachname = '' AND NEW.email = '' AND NEW.mieterID > 0
  THEN DELETE NEW;
 END IF;
END|
```

Error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; END IF; END|' at line 4
```

Thanks for helping ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would cancel an insert

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER Mieter_bi BEFORE INSERT ON Mieter FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.vorname = '' AND NEW.nachname = '' AND NEW.email = '' AND NEW.mieterID > 0
  THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Any Message';
  END IF;
END|
```

Comment: I still get the same error message at the very same location. Thanks though. The syntax seems to be wrong, but I really can't figure out why...

Comment: Still getting this syntax error.
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '|' at line 7

Comment: 100% Sure. Anyway, it worked using phpmyadmin and using your code without Delimiter in the trigger tab. Thank you very much ;)